# Vue JS Spinner for multiple component in same page ( single app)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is my Vue.js app.
The requirement is to load a separate spinner inside each component's body. Now it loads for the entire app. Any other spinner plugin is also acceptable.

## Here is the CDN

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-loading-overlay@3"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-loading-overlay@3/dist/vue-loading.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

## HTML is below

```
 <main id="app">
        <div class="clearfix" style="width:200px;height: 200px; border:1px solid; border-color: #ff0000">
            cgg <comp1-loading><loading :active.sync="visible" :can-cancel="true"></loading></comp1-loading>gg
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix" style="width:200px;height: 200px; border:1px solid; border-color: #ff0000">
        cgg <comp1-loading><loading :active.sync="visible" :can-cancel="true"></loading></comp1-loading>gg

        </div>

        <h1>Vue Loading Overlay demo</h1>
        <button @click.prevent="open()">Programmatic show</button>
        <button @click.prevent="show()">Component show, cancellable</button>
        <hr>
    </main>
```

Vue.js App Component is here. There are 2 components in the same app, so I want to load each component separately.

```
<script>
    Vue.use(VueLoading);
    Vue.component('comp1-loading', {
      data: function () {
        return {
          loading: true,
          dataList:[],
          something: false,
          message:"fgd"
        }
      },
      mounted(){
        this.fetchData();
        let loader = this.$loading.show({
                    loader: 'dots'
                });
                    setTimeout(() => loader.hide(), 3 * 1000)

      },
      methods:{
        fetchData:function(){
            var vm=this;
            vm.message="Hai this is spinner div";
        },
        serverDateFormat: function(date) {
        }
      },
      template: `<div >{{message}}</div>`
    })

    Vue.component('comp2-loading', {
      data: function () {
        return {
          loading: true,
          dataList:[],
          something: false,
          message:"fgd"
        }
      },
      mounted(){
        this.fetchData();
        let loader = this.$loading.show({
                    loader: 'dots'
                });
                    setTimeout(() => loader.hide(), 2 * 1000)

      },
      methods:{
        fetchData:function(){
            var vm=this;
            vm.message="Hai cthis is spinner div";
        },
        serverDateFormat: function(date) {
        }
      },
      template: `<div >{{message}}</div>`
    })

    Vue.use(VueLoading);
    let app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() {
            return {
                visible: true
            }
        },
        components: {
            Loading: VueLoading
        },
        methods: {
            open() {
                console.log('open was clicked, will auto hide');
                let loader = this.$loading.show({
                    loader: 'dots'
                });
                setTimeout(() => loader.hide(), 3 * 1000)
            },
            show() {
                console.log('show was clicked, click to hide');
                // do AJAX here
                this.visible = true
            }
        }
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [vue-wait](https://github.com/f/vue-wait). Works with Vue and can be used optionally with Vuex if you ever have to use it ..

> **vue-wait** helps to manage multiple loading states on the page without
>   any conflict. It's based on a **very simple idea** that manages an array
>   (or Vuex store optionally) with multiple loading states. The **built-in
>   loader component** listens to its registered loader and immediately becomes
>   a loading state.

They also have a nice [Medium post](https://medium.com/@fkadev/managing-complex-waiting-experiences-on-web-uis-29534d2d92a8) about it.